# Magento - Exclude Search Term

Tags: magento

Does anyone know if there is any way to exclude certain words from being searched for in Magento?

For example: Say I have a store that sells hats, I want to exclude the word “hats” from being searched, so if someone searches for “black hats” the it would only return results for “black”, because all the products are hats anyway, and if it allowed “hats” in the search term then it would return ALL hats.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you really need to do this, given the scenario you outlined.  Magento uses `like` or `fulltext` as available search options (set via admin > system > configuration > catalog > catalog search), and neither of those would return all hats if the search query was "black hats."

If you still feel the need to exclude certain search terms, you could either extend `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Query.php` in the local code pool, and add a method that removes any unwanted search terms.  Or - and this is the approach I would take - create a small module with an observer that catches the `controller_action_predispatch` event.  This would allow you to sanitize/modify the query parameters to remove any search terms that should excluded, before the query ever gets passed to the `ResultController.php`.

Comment: I can confirm that neither of the Magento search options solve this problem.  Both like and fulltext will still return all products.  You can see this by typing in "Pink Watches" in the search on http://twistedtime.com

Comment: @a1anm using your sample search query of "Pink Watches" it actually seems that the non-pink colors Rakumi (IDEA) Watch still contain the work Pink in the `short_description`, which usually gets searched.  Removing "Pink" from the `short_description` attribute or setting the attribute as non-searchable (at least for the quick search) should resolve your issue.